# Is serotonin syndrome something we can predict before it happens?

Tags: clinical-psychology

I’m taking currently two antidepressants. Will adding a third or fourth antidepressant to my treatment plan cause serotonin syndrome?

Comment: Your question title and its body are two different questions.  I would say the question in the title would be much more appropriate for the site.  The one contained in the body depends on too many things to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Self-help questions are explicitly off-topic. We advise you to seek professional help, especially so in complex cases like this.

Comment: It’s not self help. It can be generalized to anyone. The numbers are just examples. I could have said SWIM is taking them.

Comment: Then adapt the Q accordingly, generalize it (away from the individual), add the research you've done so far, mention types of antidepressants (there are many different ones) so that the Q becomes answerable. It's self-help and too broad and under-researched as is